# Python script to create sql query

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x

I have an excel sheet which is has columns COL_NAME, DATA_TYPE and DATA_FORMAT.
I want to read that excel using panda and create a sql query to create a table.

```
|  COL_NAME   |  DATA_TYPE   |  DATA_FORMAT
+-------------+--------------+--------------
|   a         |  VARCHAR(20) |
|   b         |  int         |
|   c         |  TIMESTAMP   | YYYY-MM-DD
|   d         |  int         |
```

Expecting output:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL table if not exist db1.table1_vw as 
select cast(a as VARCHAR(20)) as a, cast(b as int) as b, 
       cast(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(c, 'YYYY-MM-DD')) as timestamp) as c, 
       cast(d as int) as d from db1.table2;
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please show us what you have tried so far and avoid posting images. For more details, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I read the excel and converted it in to a list and successfully able to produce the query but getting issue while converting the timestamp column alone.

`df1=pd.read_excel(items['excelpath'], sheet_name='Sheet1', index_col='COL_NAME')`

`df2=pd.read_excel(items['excelpath'], sheet_name='Sheet1', index_col='DATA_TYPE')`

`df=['cast(' x for x in df1 + [' as ' + y for y in df2] + [') as ' + x for x in df1]]`